# Getting error in hot reload and showing exception

Tags: flutter, dart, hot-reload

I am getting following error on hot reload:

```
Dart Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4041 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
```

Here is log:

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(210)] Dart Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4041 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true., stack trace: #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      NavigatorState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4041:12)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:15)
#5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
#7      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:5)
#8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#9      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
#<…>
Reloaded 46 of 1237 libraries in 575ms.
```

Comment: restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with internal state management. In this case, the simplest solution is to hot-**restart** the app. Notice the difference between hot reload and hot restart: (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload)

> What is the difference between hot reload, hot restart, and full restart?
>
> Hot reload loads code changes into the VM and re-builds the widget tree, preserving the app state; it doesn’t rerun main() or initState(). (⌘\ in Intellij and Android Studio, ⌃F5 in VSCode)
>
> Hot restart loads code changes into the VM, and restarts the Flutter app, losing the app state. (⇧⌘\ in IntelliJ and Android Studio, ⇧⌘F5 in VSCode)
>
> Full restart restarts the iOS, Android, or web app. This takes longer because it also recompiles the Java / Kotlin / ObjC / Swift code. On the web, it also restarts the Dart Development Compiler. There is no specific keyboard shortcut for this; you need to stop and start the run configuration.